# Narrower indentation with imakeidx

Tags: imakeidx

I've to print an index of name. My code is the following one:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}
\makeindex[intoc=true,title=Indice dei nomi,columnsep=25pt]
```

However, when pages are a lot and the entry for a name request more than one line, I'd like to have a narrower indentation. I mean the result has to be NOT

```
    Smith, John, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,
                       16, 18, 29,
                       33, 42
```

BUT

```
Smith, John, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,
             16, 18, 29, 33, 42
```

How is it possible to reduce that indentation? thanx

Comment: This is a rather question concerning the index style, not `imakeidx`. See `idxlayout` package for example.

Comment: Already tried, but unfortunately it seems not compatible with bidi, which I use. The .tex file compiles fine, but adding something as `\usepackage[hangindent=1em]{idxlayout}` I obtain: `! Package bidi Error: Oops! you have loaded package ragged2e after bidi package. Please load package ragged2e before bidi package, and then try to run xelatex on your document again.` I'll try to produce a MWE

Comment: The index item indent is controlled (at least in `article.cls` by the command `\@idxitem`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\@idxitem` and `\subitem`, `\subsubitem` commands control the indentation of the index entries relative to the left margin.

The `\subitem` and `\subsubitem` commands use `\@idxitem` to indent further on.

The correct value depends on the OP's preferences.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\footnotesize}
\makeindex[intoc=true,title=Indice dei nomi,columnsep=25pt]




\begin{document}


\newcounter{loopcounter}

\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < 40}{%
\blindtext
\clearpage
\blindtext
\index{Brontosaurs}
\clearpage
}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\hangindent 10\p@}
\makeatother
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanx a lot